# Catching an exception type with constructor from not-const reference in C++

Tags: c++, exception, initialization, language-lawyer

Consider a struct `A` with copy-constructor deleted but having instead the constructor from not-const reference. Can one throw an object of `A` and then catch it by value as in the example program:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A&) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw A{};
    }
    catch( A ) {
    }
}
```

Both GCC and Clang allow such usage. Although MSVC prints an error:

```
C2316: 'A': cannot be caught as the destructor and/or copy constructor are inaccessible or deleted
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/P4c6Ea9fz

Indeed `A(const A&)` is deleted but `A(A&)` is accessible here. Is it a wrong diagnostics from MSVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an MSVC bug: exception objects are never ***cv*-qualified**, and handler variables are initialized from an **lvalue** that refers to them.  (The standard doesn’t actually say what the type of that lvalue is, but there’s no reason it should be const-qualified.)

Comment: Thanks, I reported MSVC bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Not-supported-catching-of-an-exception-t/1573424